# Server uploads a 0 byte file when using base64 file_put_contents

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, base64

Hi I'm dealing with a problem in my project.

The code extracts an image from a video and creates a canvas with the image extracted on it, this works fine but when trying to upload the base64 data image which is created from the video. It generates a 0 byte image on the server.

Anyone knows why??

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Document</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.dudoby.com/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
</head>

<body>

 <div class="booth">
 <video id="video" width="400" height="300" autoplay></video>
 </div>

<iframe style="visibility: hidden;" name="u-n"></iframe>

<button id="capture">Capture</button>
<form id="submitphoto" action="../success/upload_video" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<div id="output">   
</div>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/video.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

JS File:

```
(function() {

var video = document.getElementById('video'), 
vendorUrl = window.URL || window.webkitURL;

navigator.getMedia = navigator.getUserMedia ||
                     navigator.webkitGetUserMedia ||
                     navigator.mozGetUserMedia ||
                     navigator.msGetUserMedia;

    //Capture video
    navigator.getMedia({
    video: true,
    audio: false
    }, function(stream){
    video.src = vendorUrl.createObjectURL(stream);
    blob = video.src;
    video.play();

    }, function(error) {
      //An error ocurred
      //error.code
    });


//Get image
    var video, $output;
    var scale = 0.25;

    var initialize = function() {
        $output = $("#output");
        video = $("#video").get(0);
        $("#capture").click(captureImage);                
    };

    var captureImage = function() {
        var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
        canvas.width = video.videoWidth * scale;
        canvas.height = video.videoHeight * scale;
        canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(video, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

        var img = document.createElement("img");
        img.src = canvas.toDataURL();
        $output.prepend(img);

        var input = document.createElement("input");
        input.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
        input.setAttribute("name", "data");
        input.value = canvas.toDataURL();
        $output.prepend(input);

        $("#submitphoto").submit();
  };


    $(initialize);    

})();
```

PHP FiLE:

```
<?php 
session_start();
ob_start();
$logged_user = $_SESSION['valid_user'];
include("../adb/thisdb.php");
error_reporting(0);

$file = $_POST['data'];
$img = str_replace('data:image/png;base64,', '', $file);
file_put_contents('../video_streaming/testimg.png', base64_decode($img));




ob_flush();
?>
```

EDIT>FIXED: After trying lots of things, I've finally fixed the error by changing the form url to a direct full address.

PREVIOUS:

```
 <form target="u-n" id="submitphoto" action="../success/upload_video" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

WORKING ONE:

```
 <form target="u-n" id="submitphoto" action="https://www.dudoby.com/success/upload_video" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Comment: Can't see anywhere where you add a `data` field to your form. Where is `$_POST['data']` supposed to come from?

Comment: @Phil It comes from the generated image: "img.setAttribute("name", "data");" this tag adds onclick to the "output" div which is inside of a form.

Comment: But `<img>` tags aren't form fields. Any data associated with them is not included with a form submission. Only `<input>`, `<textarea>`, `<select>`, `<button>` et al elements add form data

Comment: @Phil so how should I store the data? Using which tag, any suggestions to fix this problem?

Comment: I'd go with `<input type="hidden">` but it's really your choice

Comment: Check your browser's *Network* console and look at the `POST` request data

Comment: @Phil Well, suddenly It started to work, Idk how lol but It's working now with the input hidden. Thank you Phil.

Comment: @Phil I think I found the error: After changing "../success/update.video.php" in my form to a full address "https: // www. dudoby. com/upload_video" it seems to work. Maybe cause of the https thingy...